# how to use the gcc assembly command (.type)?

Tags: gcc, assembly

**For example:**

```
.globl x;
.type x, "funciton" ;
x:
....
```

I want to know ,how to understand the command .type?

Answer (score 10):

This is a assembler directive. It does not represent any code or data, just meta information, which can for instance appear in a debugger or may be needed during link time.

This sets the type information of the variable x to "function". Other types are "object" or "common".

You can find a more in detail explanation on http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Type.html#Type .